# Inno-Setup not removing entries in Programs and Features

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to build our installer.  When I uninstall, the entry created in the "Programs and Features" control panel isn't removed.

We define CurUninstallStepChanged to remove a file and InitializeUninstall to ensure our Install isn't "active" (running).  But I didn't think that would cause the entry to remain after an uninstall.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 1):

"Programs and Features" values are read from registry.
You need to delete appropriate registry keys to delete your item from this category.
By default Inno Setup generates installer/uninstaller which creates/deletes these keys.

Are you doing something extra in your script which

> a) writes additional registry keys?
>
> b) prevents from deleting them?